# android - can't get MediaPlayer to work

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

so this is my first question here on stackoverflow, so take it easy on me ^^

Since some days I got into android developing. As a first little project I want to develop a soundboard app. Sadly I can't get the damn MediaPlayer to work. Either it gives no error and I can't hear a thing (volume maxed) or I get an error when I want to prepare the MediaPlayer.

I call the playSound(View) event, when clicking on a button. Inside the function, I'd like to play a mp3 file from the apps resources. Here is my current code following that you'll find a link where you can see, how I added the mp3 file to the apps resources. I googled a lot and tried as much as I understand right now but I can't get it to work.. Do you have any ideas what might be wrong with the code?

```
public void playSound(View v)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse("android.resource://mypackagename/res/raw/einemetallischebitterkeit"));
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            builder.setMessage(e.toString());
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }

    }
```

[mp3 file in app resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jiV5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should  use like this

```
InputStream mymp3 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.einemetallischebitterkeit);
```

Comment: Can you tell me where to put this? Or how to use it?

I also tried following code line to set the data source - still get error when preparing the media player // 
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.einemetallischebitterkeit).getFileDescriptor());